# How would I check the integrity of a hash in Perl?

Tags: perl

I was wondering how I could ensure a hash is intact when it imported into Perl from an XML file?

The XML file holds a list of Guest OS names supported by VMware and the platforms they run on (32 bit, 64-bit).

The best I can think of is to create a loop and run through the hash looking to see if every key has the required sub keys.

Any better ideas?

Here is a sample of the XML file, it is a pretty large file.

```
<platforms>
  <asianux-64>
    <name>Asianux 3</name>
    <type>64-bit</type>
  </asianux-64>
  <asianux3>
    <name>Asianux 3</name>
    <type>32-bit</type>
  </asianux3>
  <debian3>
    <name>Debian GNU/Linux 3</name>
    <type>32-bit</type>
  </debian3>
  <debian3-64>
    <name>Debian GNU/Linux 3</name>
    <type>32-bit</type>
  </debian3-64>
  <debian4>
    <name>Debian GNU/Linux 4</name>
    <type>32-bit</type>
  </debian4>
  <debian4-64>
    <name>Debian GNU/Linux 4</name>
    <type>64-bit</type>
  </debian4-64>
  <debian5>
    <name>Debian GNU/Linux 5</name>
    <type>32-bit</type>
  </debian5>
  <debian5-64>
    <name>Debian GNU/Linux 5</name>
    <type>64-bit</type>
  </debian5-64>
</platforms>
```

** REDO **

Ok let me try again,

I have an XML file that holds a list of support Operating Systems for VMware. I treat the XML file like a simple "database". My script reads from the file into a hash in my script. This hash is used to insert the OS name and platform into final output my script creates.

My problem is verifying that the XML file has not been tampered in such a way that would prevent the file from being imported into the hash.

Pretty much what I need is just a way to verify that the required keys are present.

I was thinking a simple loop through the hash looking for the required would be sufficient.

Is there anything better I can do?

Comment: How intense does the check need to be? Wouldn't it just fail to parse? What action would you take if it's corrupt? Does it need to be secure? This is too vague to answer as is

Comment: Sorry let me add a bit more depth to the question.

Comment: @ Emil Vikstrom, I parse it using `XML::Simple`.

Answer (score 2):

As others noted, question is quite vague. One option comes to mind, use XML validation to do the task, here using [Relax NG](http://relaxng.org/tutorial-20011203.html):

```
use XML::LibXML;
my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file('thing.xml');
my $rng = XML::LibXML::RelaxNG->new(string => <<ENDSCHEMA);
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<element name="platforms" xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0">
  <zeroOrMore>
    <element>
      <anyName/>
      <element name="name"> <text/> </element>
      <element name="type"> <text/> </element>
    </element>
  </zeroOrMore>
</element>
ENDSCHEMA

$rng->validate($doc);
```

Comment: Yeah I just realized that the question is vauge, let me update it.

Comment: @Solignis - if the validation passes, you can be pretty sure that every first-level element contains what it should. Note that `validate` throws exception, so you need to put it into `eval` or use `Try::Tiny` to catch and provide an error.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, if I understand what you are asking for, you want to check that a given hash has exactly a given set of keys.

You can do a simple post-verification:

```
my @required_keys = qw( foo bar baz );

my @missing_keys = grep !exists $hash{$_}, @required_keys;

die "Missing some required keys: @missing_keys\n" if @missing_keys;

die "Extra keys found.\n" if @required_keys != keys %hash;
```

Or you could use a locked hash to prevent insertion of invalid keys:

```
use Hash::Util qw( lock_keys );

my %hash;
my @allowed_keys = qw( foo bar baz );

lock_hash( %hash, @allowed_keys );

%hash = parse_config_file();  # Fatal error if a disallowed key is set.

die "Missing some keys\n" if @allowed_keys != keys %hash;
```

Comment: I like your idea of locking the hash. If this storm around me does not knock out my power I will give that a try. Is `Hash::Util` part of the Perl core?

Comment: @Solignis, yes Hash::Util is part of core.

Comment: Actually I had a bit of a brain storm, if the hash is going to pretty "static" would it be a better idea to just stick the entire hash in the script. That way perl would just error out if the hash is "broken". What do you think? The only reason I am using an XML file is because I have made about 15 revisions to this script and it is easier for me.

Comment: @Solignis, IMO, configuration files are a good thing.  Here's what I would do in your position:  I'm a big fan of Moose, and would create an application object, I'd use MooseX::SimpleConfig and MooseX::GetOpt to handle reading my config file and command line options.  I'd use Moose's strange, but useful, type system to validate my config settings.  http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX::SimpleConfig  http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX::GetOpt   This gets pretty far from core Perl, but to really use Perl effectively, you have got to learn to use CPAN.

Comment: very nice I will look into that.

Comment: Do you know of any good guide on writing YAML? I am not familiar with YAML.

Answer (score 1):

why wouldn't you trust that the import is working?

maybe...

print out the hash as XML and diff ?

Comment: Its not that I don't trust the import, I am trying to prevent users from possibly fouling up the file. I am going to distribute my script and this file is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sha1sum` on the original file, then loop-through the hash and create a tmp-file and compare the sha1sums.

Comment: There's probably no guarantee that the output order is going to be the same as the input order, given he's reading it into a hash. This would mean that the SHAs are going to be different.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of the required keys, you can use the [exists](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html) function to make sure that the required key actually exists:

```
my @requiredKeys = qw(foo bar barfoo foobar);
foreach my $key (@requiredKeys) {
   if (not exists $myHash{$key}) {
        print qq(Missing required key "$key"\n);
   }
}
```

You don't have to go through the entire hash -- Just look for the keys required.

Comment: Yeah this is close to what I was thinking, I like your idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

hmmmm somewhat primitive, but use `Data::Dumper` to print the hash contents to the console, and take a look at it.

Comment: Yeah I guess that would work, I was looking more for a way to have the script automagcally do it, but the more I think about it if I just lock the file down and hide in the /etc/ dir it would be less likley to be tampered with.

Comment: @tchrist, I think you meant [Data::Dump](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dump).  It's cpan.org, not .com.

Comment: @cjm: Right. I’ll delete the wrong comment since I can no longer edit it.

Answer (score 0):

your edits indicate you want to validate the XML structure.

you should associate a DTD or XSD and get a perl DTD validation lib

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition

Comment: Yeah that pretty much sums it up, I just want to be sure the file is not tampered with, if is tampered with I cannot guarantee it will work correctly in the script.